# Accessing static properties in Python

Tags: python

I am relatively new to Python and was hoping someone could explain the following to me:

```
class MyClass:
  Property1 = 1
  Property2 = 2

print MyClass.Property1 # 1
mc = MyClass()
print mc.Property1 # 1
```

Why can I access Property1 both statically and through a MyClass instance?

Comment: Because that's how class variables work?

Comment: @SilentGhost: Yes, Python class variables work this way, but this behavior is not required and I am unable to find an explanation for it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The code

```
class MyClass:
  Property1 = 1
```

creates a class `MyClass` which has a dict:

```
>>> MyClass.__dict__
{'Property1': 1, '__doc__': None, '__module__': '__main__'}
```

Notice the key-value pair `'Property1': 1`. 
When you say `MyClass.Property1`, Python looks in the dict `MyClass.__dict__` for the key `Property1` and if it finds it, returns the associated value `1`.

```
>>> MyClass.Property1
1
```

When you create an instance of the class,

```
>>> mc = MyClass()
```

a dict for the instance is also created:

```
>>> mc.__dict__
{}
```

Notice this dict is empty. When you say `mc.Property1`, Python first looks in `mc.__dict__` for the `'Property1'` key. Since it does not find it there, it looks in the dict of `mc`'s class, that is, `MyClass.__dict__`.

```
>>> mc.Property1
1
```

Note that there is much more to the story of [Python attribute access](https://web.archive.org/web/20170629142853/http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_attributes_and_methods/python_attributes_and_methods.html). (I haven't mentioned the important rules concerning descriptors, for instance.) But the above tells you the rule for most common cases of attribute access.

Comment: +1 for detailed description of the mechanism, but this is also a perfect opportunity to explicitly state a fundamental property of Python: Almost everything is or acts a lot like an object, including class definitions.

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense.

Comment: "it looks in the dict of `mc`'s parent class" should read "it looks in the dict of `mc`'s class", no?

Comment: It should be noted that `Property1` and `Property2` aren't really properties, but mere attributes.

Comment: How does one create a static property?

Comment: FYI -- the link to cafepy is dead.